# In Real-Time, where do we deploy Extensible Authentication Protocol(EAP) in Wireless Networks?

Tags: authentication, wireless, protocols

I have heard that the EAP protocol has authentication capabilities for wireless networks too. But I am not able to get how it is deployed in real time as I know that whenever I need to connect to my router, I just type in the password and it's done but where EAP in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in the average home Wi-Fi, not even in SOHO, it's mostly used in enterprise environment, hence the WPA/WPA2 Enterprise...

This is done when you try to authenticate to a WPA/WPA2 Enterprise AP, which mean you need to setup a [RADIUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS) server to process the EAP Auth.

Sometimes also called [802.1x/EAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X).

**UPDATE FROM COMMENTS**

This is in order to enhance security now that the AAA is done trough wired communication and not trough the air (The challenge/response can't be sniffed/cracked)

Comment: Thanks for the response!           But I was wondering what is the process like. Suppose I go to some enterprise and I want to connect to the Wifi Network. So I get the desired credentials and key in the credentials when asked by the authentication process. In this case am I getting the authenticated by the router or by some AAA server? Moreover, if I am being authenticated by some AAA, why can't the router just authenticate me, why would I need a special server for that?

Comment: It's the RADIUS server that does the AAA, and this is to **enhance security** as the RADIUS server is now connected trough cable and the traffic can't be sniffed with a monitor mode antennae. So the Challenge/Response can't be sniffed/cracked. That's how the IEEE Specification defines it, so... I'm not sure what you want to hear/read. I really hope this helps.